# Using XSLT merge 2 XML, which come from PHP transformToXML

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I am beginner in PHP, XSLT.  Found solution for transform XML using XSLT:

```
$xml = Array2XML::createXML('Document', $result);
$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('Teema.xsl');
$processor = new XSLTProcessor();
$processor->importStyleSheet($xsl);
$results=$processor->transformToXML($xml);
$results=$processor->transformToUri($xml,"NewTeema.xml" );
```

But, what to do if I have 2 or more XMLs? 
This $xml is not file, and I dont want to save each xml, like file on server (because it is was converted response json). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the XSLT you can load additional document using the `document()` function.

Another possibility is to register a PHP function that loads the file and returns the value or DOM node.

Answer (score 0):

Good solution, but I decided to merge 2 json, like this: 
  json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($result, 
  true),json_decode($resultProducts, true)));
And the use  = Array2XML::createXML('Document', $result);